# two vagrant box with same IP, issue

Tags: vagrant, ip, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have started using vagrant and I have one question. the two have the same IP and I just use one at time but when I turn off the first (vagrant halt) and turn on the second (vagrant up), I can't access the secound one trough IP. It is like the IP is attached to first one even when off.
I think the easy way to fix it is change de IP but I woud like to know why this happening

Thank you